# Why is Twitter not shortening my URL; which share functionality should I use?

Tags: twitter, sharing, twitter-api

I am currently using the share functionality of Twitter, but for some reason it's not shortening my URL. Why? And how can I fix this?

For example, if you click the link below you will see that my URL is not being shortened:

[https://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com/really-long-url-that-does-not-get-shortened&text=Random text here for sure..](https://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com/really-long-url-that-does-not-get-shortened&text=Random%20text%20here%20for%20sure..)

How do I get Twitter to shorten it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is doing it just fine - after you post it. You can tell by seeing that the left over character count does not reflect the length of the full URL.